# Protobuf gradle plugin for android generates java files for all variant

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, protocol-buffers

I have a little problem with understanding why the protobuf java source generation works on Android the way it works now. Could please somebody explain me, why does the plugin generate java sources for a proto file **for all variants**? I do not see the point. I guess when you place different proto files, for example, different build types (debug, release), then, in the end, you will get different generated java sources. But why would we need this in the first place? In my understanding of the different environments, builds, we should use the same proto files, the same domain description. Why **can't** we just generate sources for main sources? I tried it to be working that way, but w/o success.

Comment: It will be helpful if you will provide sample to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I skipped that because this is really about the very basic and recommended way of using protobuf plugin on Android. I would be just copying the example codes.